# Can a SQLite Database hold as much as a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I am used to working with PHp and MySQL, I an now trying to build a code snippet manager program with C#.

I was planning to store:  **Title, Description, Language, License, Tags, Source Code**
 into a database.

Since this will be a desktop program, I was thinking I could use an SQLite database to hold all this for each code snippet.

I have never used SQLite before, eveyone in PHP usually prefers MySQL over SQLite.  So I am not sure if this is the route to go or not.

The source code will take up a lot of space, especially when there are hundreds of them.

So my question is there a limit on what SQLite can hold or handle?  If not is there something else that would handle this better for this type of application?

Comment: Please give an esimate of the amount of data that will need to be in the database

Comment: Default blob/string size is 1 billion bytes: http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Comment: @vinny: That'd be a damn large code snippet! (Mind you, I've encountered people who had source files that large; the files were generated by EDA tools IIRC…)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the default page size of 1024 bytes, an SQLite database is limited in size to 2 terabytes (241 bytes).

further details about SQLite can be found [here](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html)

Comment: So it looks like I should be ok.  I wasn't sure since everything is stored in a file

Answer (score 2):

If it's going to be a C# program, consider using MSSQL Server Compact, check it out here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact